# C/Linux: Uses of thread synchronization

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization

I'm having a hard time understanding thread synchronization. I'm given the following thread function:

```
void *thread_function(void *unused)
{
    long aux;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        aux = count;
        aux++;
        usleep(random() % 10);
        count = aux;

    }

    return NULL;
}
```

`count` is a global variable initialized at 0. If I run this function with N number of threads (for example 4), `count` fluctuates around the value 1000.

Why is that happening, and what should be the correct value of count? If I put a semaphore, `sem_wait` before the for loop, and `sem_post` after the for loop, does that mean that my threads are not running in parallel anymore? Where should I put `sem_wait` and `sem_post` in order for my threads to be correctly synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that operations are atomic. Now assume that they are not, which is the case in real systems.

Being a global variable, `count` can be accessed by all threads in the system. This means that, without synchronization, all threads will perform the following operations in a non-deterministic and interleaved way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    aux = count;
    aux++;
    usleep(random() % 10);
    count = aux;

}
```

To sum up, in each iteration of the loop each thread will have a copy of the value of count at a given time instant, increment that copy (`aux++`) and then count will be assigned the local value `count = aux;`.

Problem 1: The value `count` read by each thread may vary across threads as threads execute because one thread may be reading a value that is being modified by another thread (or several) at a time instant immediately after (remember, operations are not atomic and can be executed in an interleaved manner).

Problem 2: The value assigned to count is not protected by any locking mechanism which means that several threads may be executing this instruction in an interleaved manner or even at the same time (for instance, in a multiprocessor system this is possible). This means that one of the threads executing (which you don't know what it is) will set the value of `count` to `aux` in `count = aux`.

A simple example of a possible execution scenario:

For instance, let's assume three threads. Thread 1 reads value count = 100 and is preempted. Thread 2 reads value 100 and executes for some time setting count to (let's say) 300 and then it is preempted. Finally, thread 3 reads value 300 and executes some loop iterations. If Thread 1 executes again and sets the value `count = aux`, after one loop iteration the value will be set to 101. See the problem!

Synchronization is needed to make sure that only one thread is doing the read, increment and assignment, in fact to make operations behave as if they were atomic.

---

Q: If I put a semaphore, `sem_wait` before the for loop, and `sem_post` after the for loop, does that mean that my threads are not running in parallel anymore?

A: That means that each thread will interleave the execution of the for loop. For instance, thread 1 will execute let's say 100 iterations of the for loop, thread 2 will execute 200 iterations, etc. Remember: the scheduler controls the execution of each thread and therefore the number of iterations is not controlled by the user. Your code is synchronized but not in an ideal manner.

---

Q: Where should I put `sem_wait` and `sem_post` in order for my threads to be correctly synchronized?

A: You should use semaphores for the smallest number of operations possible that require synchronization in order to benefit as most from concurrent/parallel code execution. For instance, using semaphores your code could be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    sem_wait(...);
        count++;
    sem_post(...);
}
```

You don't need `aux` anymore as the semaphore ensures that only one thread is incrementing the value of `count`.

Note, as you are using threads you can also use mutexes instead of semaphores.

I hope this clarifies your doubts.